# CSS effects issue with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a menu bar using three effects:

```
.transition{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.rounded{
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
         border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
}

.shadow{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
        -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
         box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}
```

these work fine with Chrome and FF but not with IE9. help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE9 doesn't support most of the CSS3 features. [See this link to see valid features](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-support-ie9/) and [this link for Microsoft reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the transitions, it's because IE 9 doesn't support CSS transitions - http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions .